# Learning two languages in a year. For example, is C# and JavaScript a good idea?

Tags: programming-languages

I know [C#](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29), but I am not deep in it. JavaScript is hot and used at work as well so knowing that won't hurt. What are your takes on picking a new language when you haven't really gone DEEP with your first. Oh, don't forget there is [ASP.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET) and its amazing life cycle to grasp.

Comment: If you have a chance to use asp.net, it should come rather natural to practice the entire stack: c#, dhtml (html+dom+javascript), and sql for starters. Just find a project you'd have fun to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think learning C# and JavaScript is a good choice - they're quite different languages, the experience will be worth it.

Chosing languages for different purposes (like C# and JavaScript) or of different paradigms (C and [Haskell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haskell_%28programming_language%29)) is the ideal, since you won't overload yourself with too much information of the same things, nor will you confuse yourself with similar concepts.

Avoid learning, for example, C# and Java or C and C++ at the same time. The first case will tire you, and the second will get you very confused.

Also, learning a second language quite early can be good. If you spend too much time coding only in one language, you'll have a hard time learning new idioms.

Comment: Excellent! Like yin and yang. much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Javascript contrasts quite well with C# - and also quite important is one of the most (if not the most) widespread languages in current use. This means you would not only be learning a very important language in its own right, but also something to contrast against C# and thereby giving comments like "C# is a statically typed language" a lot more meaning.

Comment: Cheers for that fella. Things are getting clearer.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't pick up a language in about three weeks to a models level of proficiency, you might be in the wrong field.

Eight weeks would be fine. That's about four languages in a typical two-semester year.

You'll be googling the libraries for life anyway.

C++ is an exception. You can learn to write idomatic C++ in about 10 weeks, and probably two years to read most C++ stuff.

Comment: True true, one can easily pick up the syntax of a new language fairly quickly, but it takes time to go really deep with that language.

Answer (score 1):

C# and JavaScript would be fine languages to learn. Both are very useful practically, and both have interesting language-nerd aspects to them.

Answer (score 0):

My current situation is somewhat similar: I started a new job a few months ago, and I'm learning PHP and the [Interactive Data Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDL_%28programming_language%29) (IDL) simultaneously for the job. They're very different in a lot of ways. PHP is pretty similar to other languages I've worked with (C, Perl, etc.), so it has come pretty easy. IDL is a bit odd to my way of thinking, so it's going slower. Thus, I'm finding that it can be challenging to learn two languages at once ... especially since I'm in my "extremely late 30's" ;->.

That said, from what you've stated, I assume you're using C# on the job and would be learning JavaScript to use there too. So, you've got plenty of incentive - and presumably time - to learn them and get paid for it. I don't know C#, but I have done a fair amount of C and a bit of Java as well as JavaScript, and think they aren't too much different - at least in syntax, so think you'll be fine.

If you're doing this entirely on your own time (and maybe dime), I'd suggest only taking on one other language in a year. It's up to you, but I don't think there would be enough time to devote to learning the languages and living the rest of your life.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the reply PTBNL, yea I use C# on the job and we also use JavaScript, the UX team handles most of it, but back-end devs are looking to take that over (team am on). So yea, thanks again.